# Meteor: Unable to Deploy, requires Node v0.10.40 or later

Tags: node.js, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I recently updated my meteor to version 1.2.0.2 and now I can't seem to be able to deploy. I get the following error.

```
 [104.236.123.456] error: Forever detected script exited with code:                                1[104.236.123.456]
[104.236.123.456] error: Script restart attempt #16[104.236.123.456]
[104.236.123.456] Meteor requires Node v0.10.40 or later.[104.236.123.456]
```

I am using mup, so I changed the version in mup.json from 0.10.36 to 0.10.40 and it still throws the same error. I am using digital ocean, should this be an update to the node version in digital ocean? I have tried doing a search for node update but nothing shows up, so not sure if this is the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating your node version inside `mup.json` won't actually upgrade the node version installed on the server, have you tried using `mup setup` again to reinstall node on the droplet ?

Comment: thank you, first time didn't work because I didn't realize the version was commented out. But uncommented and now works. You da man!